# How to remote connect into a Windows machine running Microsoft Windows 11 Pro Workstation OS from an iPad on different networks

Tags: windows, desktop, remote, ipad, workstation

I am trying to set up a few computers connected to different networks (e.g. different countries) in such a way that I remotely connect between them, but also use an iPad Pro 12.9 inch to remote desktop into them.

Since it is a work in progress, I thought I take it step by step, so I would need advice for connecting to one of the Windows machines from my iPad.

My Windows machine is running Microsoft Office 11 Pro for Workstation OS and has a single account to which I log into using the PIN method. My Microsoft Account is connected on the Windows Machine.

I have no idea how to set up neither machine (i.e. iOS or Windows) to be able to use the Remote Desktop app from the iPad.

I tried first using the Remote Desktop app for machines on the same network, but cannot establish a connection since it seems whatever credentials I use (e.g. email used for Microsoft Account and the Microsoft password, Windows User and PIN) don't allow me to log in.

I have also installed Tailscale on both machines, but was of no help.

I would say I definitely miss some steps in setting up the machines.

Hence, can anybody help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use TeamViewer or AnyDesk to remote into your PC. So that you don't have to type in the password (TeamViewer) or need someone else to allow it (AnyDesk), you could setup a easy-to-access password, that works all the time. Additionally I would whitelist your ID in either one of those applications, so that nobody has access to your PC through TeamViewer/Anydesk even when they have the password.

To setup the unattended access review these articles either of [AnyDesk](https://support.anydesk.com/knowledge/unattended-access) or [TeamViewer](https://community.teamviewer.com/English/kb/articles/108689-set-up-unattended-access).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did use to use TeamViewer, but my account got locked as they considered I was using it for "Business purposes", which was not true. Additionally, I would like to learn how to use the Windows Remote Desktop app. Nonetheless, thank you for your suggestion!